# Функция для счета кол-ва единиц в двоичном представлении десятичного числа. с++

Tags: c++

2(дес) = 10(дв) => функция должна выдать 1.

5(дес) = 101(дв) => функция должна выдать 2.

Как это сделать?

Comment: числа по степеням двойки перебирайте (битовый сдвиг влево на 1) и логическое И искомым числом делайте, если не нуль +1 к результату

Answer (score 0):

**MathHelper.h**

```
#ifndef MATHHELPER_H
#define MATHHELPER_H

#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(const int n);
int printPrimeDivisors(const int n);
int summ(int n, int p); //n - число, p - разрядность
vector <int> sortByColumnOfelements(vector <int> inputVector);

struct number
{
    int value;
    int entry;
    int bin;
    number()
    {
        entry = 0;
    };
    number(int ivalue)
    {
        value = ivalue;
        entry = 0;
    };
    number(int ivalue, int ientry)
    {
        value = ivalue;
        entry = ientry;
    };
};


#endif //MATHHELPER_H
```

**MathHelper.cpp**

```
#include "mathHelper.h"
#include <map>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector <int> bubleSort(vector <number> inputVector)
{
    vector <int> tmpVector;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputVector.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputVector.size() - 1; j++)
        {
            if(inputVector[j + 1].entry > inputVector[j].entry)
            {
                swap(inputVector[j + 1], inputVector[j]);
            }

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < inputVector.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        tmpVector.push_back(inputVector[i].value);
    }
    return tmpVector;
}

vector <int> map2vec(map <int, int> &inputMap)
{
    vector <int> outputVector;
    for (map <int, int>::iterator it = inputMap.begin(); it != inputMap.end(); it ++)
    {
        outputVector.push_back(it->first);
    }
    return outputVector;
}

vector <int> sortByColumnOfelements(vector <int> inputVector)
{
    map <int, int> tmpMap;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputVector.size(); i++)
    {
        map<int, int>::iterator it;
        it = tmpMap.find(inputVector[i]);
        if (it != tmpMap.end())
        {
            it->second++;
        }
        else
        {
            pair <int, int> tmpPair(inputVector[i],1);
            tmpMap.insert(tmpPair);
        }
    }
    vector <number> tmpVector;
    for (map<int, int>::iterator it = tmpMap.begin(); it != tmpMap.end(); it++)
    {
        tmpVector.push_back(number(it->first,it->second));
    }

    return bubleSort(tmpVector);
}


bool isPrime(const int n)
{
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return n > 1;
}

int printPrimeDivisors(const int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0 && isPrime(i)){
            //std::cout << i << "\n"; вывод делителей
            sum += 1;
        }
    return sum;
}

//n - число, p - разрядность
int summ(int n, const int p) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0){
        sum += n % p;
        n /= p;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "mathHelper.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fin("test.txt");
    if(fin.bad())
    {
        cout << "Up's. I can't find file" << endl;
    }
    int k;
    vector <int> myVector;
    while(fin >> k)
    {
        myVector.push_back(k);
        cout << k;
        cout << endl;
    }

    vector <int> sortedVector = sortByColumnOfelements(myVector);
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedVector.size() - 1; i++ )
    {
        cout << sortedVector[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl << "p2, p3, p4" << endl;

    cout << summ(15, 2) << endl; //двоичная : 1111 = 4
    cout << summ(5, 2) << endl; //двоичная : 101 = 2
    cout << summ(9, 10) << endl; //двоичная : 9 = 9
    cout << summ(111, 10) << endl; //десятичная : 111 = 3
    cout << printPrimeDivisors(99) << endl; // 11*3*3 = 2
    cout << printPrimeDivisors(5) << endl; // Без учёта 1, но с учётом себя
    cin >> k;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: подразумевалась рекурсия что ли? на кой она тут, если элементарно заменяется циклом?